# How to transmit hand gesture data from a laptop to Raspberry-pi

Tags: python, pi-2, opencv

I am making a hand gesture bot. In this hand gestures are detected from a laptop using image processing (used OpenCV & Python). I don't know how to transmit real-time output wirelessly of image processing to Raspberry-pi so that robot can move in a particular direction using gestures.

Comment: Your question is really "how can I send some data from a PC to a Raspberry Pi?".  Google that exact sentence and I bet you'll find something :-)

Comment: It's not clear what this has specifically to do with Raspberry Pi. If it's just a question about coding data and sending wirelessly between two computers, other sites, like stackoverflow,com, will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python itself and its [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#module-http.client) module or [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) and send data or commands to a Python webserver running on your Pi. For a python webserver you could use Python Flask or even Python's [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) module.

Comment: How to send image processing output in python to server?

Comment: something like: if hand gesture detected, send the string "forward" to server. You don't need to actually send image processing output. You send whatever command you desire. For communication between server and client you can check the links I posted in my answer.

Comment: Can you pls give code for client and server side. Need it for college project. I am new to this.

Comment: @KarthikKarkera unfortunately Stack Exchange is not the place to ask others for doing college projects. Maybe you could try a freelance jobs website like Upwork.